# FAN Native ads refresh:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again

Tags: out-of-memory, refresh, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I met a OOM-issue of FAN native ads with the latest version 4.28.0.I want the FAN native ads refresh every 10 seconds,so I create a new instance of NativeAd and load ad every 10s.Implemented as the official docs says. **I reproduced this issue in official demo too.To reproduce easily,I changed the interval time from 10s to 2s.** here is the sample code of my test:

```
private void showNativeAd() {
    nativeAd = new NativeAd(getContext(), mAdunit);
    nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
            // Ad error callback
            Log.e(TAG,"failed-->" + error.getErrorMessage());
            //refresh after 2s
            requestDelay(2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG,"loaded-->");
            // Add the Ad view into the ad container.
            //...

            //refresh after 2s
            requestDelay(2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            // Ad clicked callback
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            // On logging impression callback
        }
    });

    // Request an ad
    nativeAd.loadAd();
  }

private void requestDelay(int millseconds){
   if (handler == null){
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   }
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showNativeAd();
    }
  },millseconds);
}
```

It is running well at the beginning, **but about an hour later,crashed**.here is the crash log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
 at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1327)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:590)
 at com.facebook.ads.internal.m.b$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue seems be fixed in the latest version v4.28.1.